# React JS render list data in separate row

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function

I am facing an issue in React Js. I want to show names data in each separate row.

```
  const names = ['James', 'John', 'Paul', 'Ringo'[![\]][1]][1];
```

My Code:

```
return (
<div class="col-lg-8 bar-name">
  <div>
    {names.map(filteredName => (
      <li>
        {filteredName}
      </li>
    ))}
  </div>
</div>)
```

[image]

How can i use in div element ? What should i do?

can anyone help me?

Comment: Please also share the complete code where your are rendering the right side of the row. i.e row with Ryan and eric

Comment: Please make sure what exactly you want. Your question is not that clear. The array your provided does not make sense.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add elements to want to be displayed alongside in the List tag.
Example:

```
return (
<div class="col-lg-8 bar-name">
  <div>
    {names.map(filteredName => (
      <li>
        {filteredName} 
       <div>
        Ryan
       </div>
       <div>
        Eric
       </div>
      </li>
    ))}
  </div>
```

)